# Can't catch Ctrl+C in input() with Spyder 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ipython, spyder

How do I capture Ctrl+C in line and exit the program as user enters it. I am using Python 3.7.3 on IPython 7.4.0 on spyder 3.3.3 on windows 64 bit machine with 8 GB RAM.

The most important thing is that when I run this program on windows powershell it works, this is happening only with spyder.

I tried using threads, KeyboardInterrupt, etc. but nothing works. I also saw lots of post regarding this but none is useful. Thing is that everytime python fails to capture Ctrl + C.

```
while True:
    line = input()
    if ('line contains Ctrl+C')
        break
    print(line)

print("Exiting")
```

I expect that after pressing Ctrl + C , program will print "Exiting" and stop execution.

Comment: There are usually two ways to handle input termination: The first is to use a *sentinel* input, like for example an otherwise invalid value (e.g. `-1` when inputting positive numbers); The second is to have the user press the "end of file" keyboard combination (`Ctrl-Z` on Windows, `Ctrl-D` on Linux or macOS) and detect that.

Comment: When you run your script from PowerShell, the python.exe process inherits a console. PowerShell is otherwise not involved. You could run python.exe from a shortcut or the Win+R dialog with the same result. A cooked read in the console generates a control event when the user presses Ctrl+C. This event gets handled by Python's C runtime library by calling Python's signal handler, which in turn interrupts the main thread (if possible) to call the `SIGINT` handler, which defaults to a function that raises `KeyboardInterrupt`. In an IDE, Ctrl+C has to be emulated, if it's even supported.

Comment: I don't know what Spyder does, but in IDLE, the basic IDE that's included with Python, Ctrl+C is implemented by calling `_thread.interrupt_main` in the child python.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing there is what happens when you press Ctrl+C. It just stops. That being said, you might be able to except `KeyboardInterrupt`. Have you tried this?

```py
import sys

try:
    #Code Stuff Goes Here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(Exiting...)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried using that still it freezes and I have to restart the kernel